# How efficient it will be to have a background thread (consumer thread) for a bolt to do operations independent of incoming tuple?

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-storm

Design : KafkaSpout --> Bolt1 -->**AggregatingBolt**

Details:

I have a aggregating bolt which after certain frequency flushes stats to DB and then send their ack signals. If there are no more incoming tuples then the tuples will time out. In this scenario, there are two adverse effects

1. KafkaSpout & Bolt1 may reprocess these tuples and resend -- not confirm about this. - will result in Duplicacy
2. Incorrect Stats due to duplicacy.

I have thought of having a background thread initiated by AggregatingBolt. The Bolt will act like producer and the thread as the consumer, it will enable to flush into DB & sending ack independent of incoming tuples.

So, coming back to my question ;), 
how efficient the solution is? Or do we have any other better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution you propose is adequate. You require another thread, since your bolt's main function is tied to receiving tuples, which means that if you only log on the reception of tuples, you won't log on regular intervals and as you said, when you're not receiving tuples and not logging, the tuples you have already received will timeout and lead to resends and incorrect counting.

Have a second thread in your bolt that logs on intervals. You of course then have to use mutex locks on the variable that your threads will share to ensure that no contention occurs. You should also make sure that your timeout period is longer than your log period, otherwise your tuples will timeout before you've logged them.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check using Tick tuples? It enables a bolt to execute at fixed intervals, with it you will not have to define a custom thread in a bolt (for simplicity's sake).

Check this article about micro-batching with storm and tick tuples, maybe it should help: http://hortonworks.com/blog/apache-storm-design-pattern-micro-batching/

Of course, it means you are storing results in-memory (JVM worker memory) before flushing into DB. So if your worker stops or crashes, you loose all what was inside your current buffer in memory. The only solution for not loosing these datas, is to use an external memory buffer such as redis for instance.

Comment: Yes, I already had moved the implementation to Tick tuples, the code looks much clean and organized !!

But the problem of worker crashing still persists as I have not used Redis. The single reason for that is inconsistency between buffer data and kafka offset on such a event. On worker crashing, the buffer data wont get lost, however kafka offset will not get committed resulting in replaying batch of tuples from kafka queue, thereby defeating the very purpose of data buffering.